# Relationship decay in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm evaluating neo4j for a project. Overall it seem to fit my needs fairly well but I have one requirement that I'm not sure about.

I need to be able to create a relationship between two nodes that decays over time.

Does neo4j support such a thing? Or does anyone know of a crafty way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think Neo4j supports such a things. Essentially, you'd like to assign a TTL value (e.g. 2 days) to a relationship?

Comment: Not exactly. It needs to decay progressively. It could be done also by creating a relationship with a timestamp and then having something like a function along these lines: score = 1 / (now() - stored_timestamp). Think of the relationship that looses "power" over time. I want to later return connected nodes sorted by the strength of the resulting relationship.

Answer (score 1):

To get the "freshest" relationships first, you could just sort the relationships in descending order by their stored timestamps.

For example:

```
MATCH (f:Foo {id: 123})-[b:BAR]->()
RETURN b
ORDER BY b.stored_timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: I would need something more along the lines of .... `RETURN f ORDER BY 1/timestamp() - b.stored_timestamp DESC`.

Comment: I assume you actually mean `1/(timestamp() - b.stored_timestamp)`? That value would be smaller for older `stored_timestamp` values, so your `ORDER BY ... DESC` clause would order more recent `stored_timestamp` values first. You could get the same effect by just using `ORDER BY b.stored_timestamp DESC`.